# Struct member size is bigger than the memory allocated for the struct

Tags: c, memory, struct, memory-management, memory-leaks

Suppose we have some struct contains one member (An array). Memory is allocated for the struct according to the size of its members (Suppose 4 bytes).
Memory is also allocated for its member.

```
struct X {
    int *arr;  
};  

int main() {
    struct X *x = (struct X *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct X));  
    x->arr = (int *)calloc(5, sizeof(int)); 
}
```

Now, what happens to the struct if the memory block size allocated for `arr` is larger than the size allocated for the struct?

Comment: Your struct has a pointer as a member (not an array). It only stores that pointer, nothing else. You can make that pointer point to wherever you want, doesn't affect the size of the struct in any way.

Comment: @S.O.M: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure contains just a pointer to `int`: when you allocate an object for an array of 5 `int` and set the `arr` member to point to this block, you have 2 allocated objects, one pointing to the other, no problem with that, but the programmer must keep track of the length of the allocated array somewhere.

As a matter of fact, if you add a `length` member to your structure, you will have an object where you can store a variable number of `int` values, an `int_vector`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct int_vector {
    int *arr;
    size_t length;
};  

struct int_vector *int_vector_alloc(size_t len) {
    struct vector *v = calloc(1, sizeof(*v));
    if (v) {
        v->length = len;
        v->arr = calloc(len, sizeof(*a->arr));
        if (v->arr == NULL) {
            free(v);
            v = NULL;
        }
    }
    return v;
}

void int_vector_free(struct int_vector *v) {
    if (v) {
        free(v->arr);
        free(v);
    }
}

void int_vector_print(const struct int_vector *v) {
    if (v) {
        const char *sep = "";
        printf("[");
        for (size_t i; i < v->length; i++) {
            printf("%s%d", sep, v->arr[i]);
            sep = ", ";
        }
        printf(" ]");
    }
}

int main() {
    struct int_vector *v = int_vector_alloc(5);
    int_vector_print(v);
    int_vector_free(v);
    return 0;
}
```